# Fastest way to join multiple MVC projects into a single one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have about 4 different MVC projects, in separate Solutions, with their own Controllers, Models and Views.

We need to join all these projects into a single Project (Solution). The new project will have an entry point (Home Page), from which you can go to any of the existing projects.

We will navigate from one project to another (one section to another - after integration) using simple navigation links.

Is `Areas` a good solution for this approach?

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200424/multiple-asp-net-mvc-projects-that-builds-as-single-asp-net-mvc-application/1362621#1362621) but i don't understand what the solution from there is.

Comment: `Areas` is your option, each appln can be added in its own area and configure routing appropriately

Comment: Exactly this is what i will do. I will make each `MVC` project as an `Area`, i will use `RazorGenerator` to create Embedded Views (i don't want to copy them across), and from the hosting project i will only reference the `Areas` projects. [here is an example](http://blog.falafel.com/work-asp-net-mvc-5-areas-different-projects/). Post your comment as an answer to mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Areas` is your option, each application can be added in its own area and configure routing appropriately